Why is my api data saying fulfilled but returning undefined?
I'm using the GameSpot API in my React Redux web app (set up with Vite). I'm seeing undefined data in my components, although Redux DevTools shows each query state as fulfilled with data visible there.
I've set up useEffect in App.jsx to merge fields from three endpoints each returning different data unique to that endpoint:

games (genres, release date)

reviews (scores)

releases (platforms, publishers, developers).


Here's my setup:
App.jsx
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import { useEffect } from 'react'
import './App.css'
import { setGames } from './features/Games/gamesSlice'
import { useGetGamesQuery, useGetReviewsQuery, useGetReleasesQuery } from './api/gamespotApiSlice'
import { Header } from './features/Header/Header'
import { GamesList } from './features/Games/GamesList/GamesList'
import { GameDetails } from './features/Games/GameDetails/GameDetails'

function App () {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { data: gamesData } = useGetGamesQuery();
  const { data: reviewsData } = useGetReviewsQuery();
  const { data: releasesData } = useGetReleasesQuery();
  useEffect(() => {
    if (gamesData && reviewsData && releasesData) {
      const mergedData = gamesData.results.map(game => {
        const review = reviewsData.results.find(review => review.game.id === game.id);
        const release = releasesData.results.find(release => release.game_api_url.includes(game.name));
        const publisher = release && release.publishers.length > 0 ? release.publishers[0] : "Unknown";
        const developer = release && release.developers.length > 0 ? release.developers[0] : "Unknown";
        return {
            ...game,
            id: game.id,
            name: game.name,
            cover: game.image,
            platform: release ? release.platform : null,
            genres: game.genres || [],
            release_year: new Date(release ? release.release_date : null).getFullYear(),
            score: review ? review.score : null,
            publisher,
            developer
        };
      });
      const sortedGames = [...mergedData].sort((a, b) => b.score - a.score);
      dispatch(setGames(sortedGames));
    }
  }, [dispatch, gamesData, reviewsData, releasesData]);
  return (
    <Router>
      <Header />
      <main>
        <section className='game-view'>
          <Routes>
            <Route path='/games/:id' element={<GameDetails />} />
            <Route path='/' element={<GamesList />} />
          </Routes>
        </section>
      </main>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;

gamespotApiSlice.js
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react";

const API_KEY = '?api_key='+ import.meta.VITE_GAMESPOT_API_KEY;
const jsonFormat = '&format=json';

export const gamespotApi = createApi({
    reducerPath: 'gamespotApi',
    baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: '/api' }),
    endpoints: (builder) => ({
        getGames: builder.query({
            query: () => `games/${API_KEY}${jsonFormat}`,
        }),
        getReviews: builder.query({
            query: () => `reviews/${API_KEY}${jsonFormat}&sort=score:desc`,
        }),
        getReleases: builder.query({
            query: () => `releases/${API_KEY}${jsonFormat}`,
        })
    })
})

export const {
    useGetGamesQuery,
    useGetReviewsQuery,
    useGetReleasesQuery
} = gamespotApi;

export default gamespotApi.reducer;

I've also tried simpler approaches (e.g., displaying setGames directly within useEffect without merging & filtering fields in the endpoint queries), but I still see undefined in components. Any advice on handling this data across endpoints or troubleshooting undefined data would be appreciated!




What you are seeing as "undefined" here are the undefined query arguments passed to your endpoints. These are the cache keys and are a stringified combination of the passed query args and the endpoint name.
See serializeQueryArgs for details:

By default, this function will take the query arguments, sort object
keys where applicable, stringify the result, and concatenate it with
the endpoint name. This creates a cache key based on the combination
of arguments + endpoint name (ignoring object key order), such that
calling any given endpoint with the same arguments will result in the
same cache key.

None of your endpoints take any arguments:
endpoints: (builder) => ({
  getGames: builder.query({
    // No query arg
    query: () => `games/${API_KEY}${jsonFormat}`,
  }),
  getReviews: builder.query({
    // No query arg
    query: () => `reviews/${API_KEY}${jsonFormat}&sort=score:desc`,
  }),
  getReleases: builder.query({
    // No query arg
    query: () => `releases/${API_KEY}${jsonFormat}`,
  })
})

And in the UI where the query hooks are called no argument is passed:
const { data: gamesData } = useGetGamesQuery();       // No query arg
const { data: reviewsData } = useGetReviewsQuery();   // No query arg
const { data: releasesData } = useGetReleasesQuery(); // No query arg

What you see in the Redux-Devtools appears to be accurate and correct based on the provided code and usage.
If for example you had an endpoint that took an argument:
getGame: builder.query({
  query: (gameId) => `games/${gameId}/${API_KEY}${jsonFormat}`,
})

const { data } = useGetGameQuery("1337");

Then you'd see a cache entry key in the Redux-Devtools that might look something like "getGame(1337)".
